# Need to get list of BI reports for users dashboard OBIEE 10g

Tags: oracle10g, reporting, obiee

I understand the process of setting up URLs for someone to get a report from BI and passing parameters BUT - how can I query the repository to find out if a user has permissions to a certain folder/report beforehand? (yes... we're still at 10g).
To clarify a bit more - we're using SSO and embedding the dashboard page in an iframe works great - they now want to see if we can put the list of reports available to a user in a "widget" style item on the page.

Answer (score 0):

First idea, OBIEE gives the possibility to add a list of report from a directory in a dashboard. Then may be that you can create a simple dashboard page and call it with the dashboard URL. I think that the user permissions are automatically applied.

Second idea, Presentation Services (Dashboard and answers) gives a web service API:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10415_01/doc/bi.1013/b31769.pdf
You can query what you want and see all permissions.

Cheers
Nico

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you are re-inventing the wheel. [Oracle's BIComposer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e10544/bicomposer.htm) has a taskflow that does just that and more, out of the box, for any custom web application implemented using ADF, but you might have to upgrade.